# Why does PHP 7.x SoapServer return XML references (e.g. href="#ref1") for non-duplicate arrays?

Tags: php, xml, soap, soapserver

I have a problem using PHP's built-in `SoapServer` to return a response containing two different arrays.  PHP thinks my `fruit` and `vegetables` arrays are duplicates (they are not).  The response uses a `Wrapper` class making use of PHP's `__get()` magic overloading method, which seems to be part of the problem.

My code works perfectly fine in PHP versions 5.3, 5.4, 5.5 and 5.6 and generates a correct SOAP XML response:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="http://test-uri/">
<SOAP-ENV:Body>
    <ns1:fooResponse>
        <result>
            <fruit>
                <item>apple</item>
                <item>orange</item>
                <item>banana</item>
            </fruit>
            <vegetables>
                <item>carrots</item>
                <item>broccoli</item>
            </vegetables>
        </result>
    </ns1:fooResponse>
</SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

The exact same code in PHP versions 7.0, 7.1 and 7.2RC2 produces the following unexpected XML, which contains a reference in the `vegetables` collection, pointing back to the `fruit` collection:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="http://test-uri/">
<SOAP-ENV:Body>
    <ns1:fooResponse>
        <result>
            <fruit id="ref1">
                <item>apple</item>
                <item>orange</item>
                <item>banana</item>
            </fruit>
            <vegetables href="#ref1"/>
        </result>
    </ns1:fooResponse>
</SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

My questions are, **why does PHP 7.x think `fruits` and `vegetables` are exactly the same, causing it to return an XML reference?  Why does the behavior change in the 7.x versions?  How can I continue using a wrapper class and the `__get()` method and achieve the same response as earlier versions of PHP?**

Here is my verifiable example, self-contained in one PHP file.  It can be run directly from the command line (no web server required):

```
$wsdl  = <<<WSDL
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<definitions name="SoapArrayTest"
                  xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
                  xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"
                  xmlns:tns="http://test-uri/"
                  xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/"
                  xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"
                  xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"
                  targetNamespace="http://test-uri/"
  >
  <types>
    <schema xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" targetNamespace="http://test-uri/">
      <complexType name="Baz">
        <sequence>
          <element name="fruit" type="tns:StringArray"/>
          <element name="vegetables" type="tns:StringArray"/>
        </sequence>
      </complexType>
      <element xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" name="BazElement" type="tns:Baz"/>
      <complexType name="StringArray">
        <sequence>
          <element name="item" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
        </sequence>
      </complexType>
      <element xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" name="StringArrayElement" type="tns:StringArray"/>
    </schema>
  </types>
  <message name="fooRequest">
  </message>
  <message name="fooResponse">
    <part name="result" type="tns:Baz"/>
  </message>
  <portType name="TestPortType">
    <operation name="foo">
      <input message="tns:fooRequest"/>
      <output message="tns:fooResponse"/>
    </operation>
  </portType>
  <binding  name="TestBinding" type="tns:TestPortType">
    <soap:binding  style="rpc" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
    <operation  name="foo">
      <soap:operation  soapAction="#foo" style="rpc"/>
      <input />
      <output >
        <soap:body  parts="result" use="literal" namespace="http://test-uri/" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"/>
      </output>
    </operation>
  </binding>
  <service  name="TestService">
    <port  name="TestPort" binding="tns:TestBinding">
      <soap:address location="http://example.com"/>
    </port>
  </service>
</definitions>
WSDL;

class Wrapper
{
  private $object;

  public function __construct($object)
  {
    $this->object = $object;
  }

  public function __get($property)
  {
    $value = $this->object->$property;
    return $value;
  }
}

function foo()
{
  $baz = new stdClass();
  $arr1 = array( "apple", "orange", "banana");
  $baz->fruit = $arr1;
  $arr2 = array("carrots", "broccoli");
  $baz->vegetables = $arr2;
  $bar = new Wrapper($baz);
  return $bar;
}

$fname = tempnam (__DIR__, "wsdl");
$f = fopen($fname,"w");
fwrite($f,$wsdl);
fclose($f);

$server = new SoapServer($fname, array('cache_wsdl' => WSDL_CACHE_NONE, 'soap_version' => SOAP_1_1));
$server->addFunction("foo");

$soapRequest = <<<XML
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="blah" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" SOAP-ENV:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
  <SOAP-ENV:Body>
    <ns1:foo>
    </ns1:foo>
  </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
XML;


$server->handle($soapRequest);
```

Updates:

- The solution to this similar question [PHP SoapClient creating XML references for identical elements, makes it unacceptable for service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9744442/php-soapclient-creating-xml-references-for-identical-elements-makes-it-unaccept) doesn't work.  My elements are not identical.  If my elements were identical I would be OK with the XML references.
- Changing the WSDL so that it contains two separate `StringArray` structures does not work
- I tried adding 'item' to my arrays like this (it didn't work):

  ```
  function foo()
  {
    $baz = new stdClass();

    $fruits = array( "item" => array("apple", "orange", "banana"));
    $baz->fruit = $fruits;

    $veggies = array("item" => array("carrots", "broccoli"));
    $baz->vegetables = $veggies;

    $bar = new Wrapper($baz);
    return $bar;
  }
  ```
- I can fix the issue in PHP 7.x by using objects with `item` property like this:

  ```
  function foo()
  {
    $baz = new stdClass();

    $fruits = new stdClass();
    $fruits->item = array("apple", "orange", "banana");
    $baz->fruit = $fruits;

    $veggies = new stdClass();
    $veggies->item = array("carrots", "broccoli");
    $baz->vegetables = $veggies;

    $bar = new Wrapper($baz);
    return $bar;
  }
  ```

  However I am not satisfied with this.  I still don't know why using arrays won't work in PHP 7.x.

Comment: PHP has a option to define classmapping, are you using it?

$classmap = array('Meeting'=>'Meeting');
$server = new SoapServer('soap.wsdl',array('classmap'=>$classmap));
$server->setClass("MySoapServer");
$server->handle();

Comment: If I use either `stdClass` or classes with classmap option, the problem goes away (see latest update in the question).  The problem is when arrays are used instead of objects - I need to know why it works in 5.x but not in 7.x.  Maybe my code was broken all along and PHP 5.x was more forgiving.

Comment: Definitely it was because it was more forgiving, but PHP has a lot of characteristics that are not documented. have you tried my other answer? I think this is the cause, can you test it?

Comment: did you file a bug report to php?

Comment: No I haven't filed a bug report yet.  I'm doubtful it's a bug because 7.x has been out for so long now.  Surely it would have been discovered by now?

Answer (score 1):

It's an old bug, it was fixed at the end of 2018 but not sure which PHP versions it is released in. Basically any referenced objects trigger this:

https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=50675

PHP 7.x has more aggressive optimizations than the old versions - my guess is it reuses the array's memory since it's not used again in the code and the second array is smaller. So for the XML encoder it looks like a reference to the same object.

A temporary fix seems to be casting to an abject and explicitly cloning it (or otherwise messing around with the variables as you already found):

```
$fruits = clone (object)array( "item" => array("apple", "orange", "banana"));
```

Otherwise you can try the latest / beta versions of PHP and see when it's fixed.

Comment: Fixed in PHP 7.2

Answer (score 0):

Your xsd seems not exactly how it needs to be. To define one element as a sequence (array), you need something like this inside Baz definition:

```
<xs:element name="fruits">
<xs:complexType>
  <xs:sequence>
    <xs:element name="fruit" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
  </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```

```
<xs:element name="vegetables">
<xs:complexType>
  <xs:sequence>
    <xs:element name="vegetable maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
  </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```

[Reference](https://www.obj-sys.com/docs/acv60/CCppUsersGuide/CCppUsersGuide40.html)

Comment: It doesn't work.  It's the same issue, except the returned XML is slightly different: `<ns1:fooResponse><result><fruits id="ref1"><fruit>apple</fruit><fruit>orange</fruit><fruit>banana</fruit></fruits><vegetables href="#ref1"/></result></ns1:fooResponse>`